# Error whilst trying to loop through files and amend and save

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm writing a VBScript file that takes all Excel xlsx files in a specific folder and modifies the content and saves it as a tab-delimited text file - that part I've got working and can do 1 file at a time.

What I cant seem to get working is looping the code to process all xlsx files within that directory - instead the code processes the first file - then throws an error message saying

> Microsoft Excel cannot access the file

and then only finishes off the first file.

```
strPath = "Y:\HUN-CHANNELS\Sales\ASRUN\WOMM_ASRUN_PARSER"

Const FromValue = ":"
Const ToValue = ""
strSafeDate = Right("0" & DatePart("d",Date), 2) & _
              Right("0" & DatePart("m",Date), 2) & DatePart("yyyy",Date) & _
              Right("0" & Hour(Now()),2) & Right("0" & Minute(Now()),2)

Dim objXL, objWB, objWS
Dim objCHNID

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(strPath)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
  If objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "xlsx" Then
    Set objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)
    Set objWS = objWB.Worksheets("ZZESSSPOTASRUNREPORT")

    objCHNID = objWS.Cells(3, 5).Value

    'Delete the first 2 rows (header rows)
    objWS.Rows("1:2").Delete

    'Format olumns B & C to 8 characters long so there are leading zeroes
    objWS.Columns(2).NumberFormat="00000000"
    objWS.Columns(3).NumberFormat="00000000"
    'Remove any Colons from Columns B & C 
    objWS.Columns(2).Replace FromValue, ToValue
    objWS.Columns(3).Replace FromValue, ToValue

    objWB.SaveAs "Y:\HUN-CHANNELS\Sales\ASRUN\WOMM_ASRUN_PARSER\REC" & _
      objCHNID & strSafeDate & ".txt", -4158
    objXL.DisplayAlerts = False
    objWB.Close
    objXL.Quit

    Set objWS = Nothing
    Set objWB = Nothing

    Set WshShell = Nothing
  End If
Next

Set objXL = Nothing
```

Comment: Have you figured out, where the error happens? You script might be too fast, and excel still has an open handle on the file/folder

Comment: It's typically a good idea to avoid modifying a collection (in this case files in a folder) at the same time you're looping over it - try collecting all of the Excel files into an array or collection, and then looping over that.